# I am calling a parent funciton in base class but returns nothing

Tags: php, oop

```
class ajay{
    function test(){
        return "sandeep";
    }
}

class Sandeep extends ajay{
    function testing(){
        parent::test();
    }
}
$objct = new Sandeep();echo $objct->testing();
```

Comment: Please add information about build results and errors (if any).

Comment: If problems can be fixed with a simple online search please don't post them on SO.

Answer (score 1):

```
There is no return data in testing function

<?php 
class ajay{
    function test(){
        return "sandeep";
    }
}

class Sandeep extends ajay{
    function testing(){
        $data = parent::test();
        return $data;
    }
}
$objct = new Sandeep();
echo $objct->testing();
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You forgot `return` in `testing()` method:

```
class ajay {
    function test(){
        return "sandeep";
    }
}

class Sandeep extends ajay{
    function testing(){
        return parent::test();
    }
}
```